# In php7.4 trying to enable the imap & mysqli mods on Ubuntu, but get error

Tags: php

I know 8.1 is out but some of the mods I use are not yet available on 8.1 so...

When I do "apt install php7.4-imap" command I get "php7.4-imap is already the newest version (1:7.4.32-2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).". If I then do "a2enmod imap" I get "ERROR: Module imap does not exist!".

Basically I have the "extension=imap" and "extension=mysqli" enabled in /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini. Those are the only "extensions=" settings I have enabled, and they both get errors so I am assuming I have a setup/config issue?

Where do I get this resolved, or are there other suggestions on where better errors might be found?

BTW: The error is showing up as a blank screen that just says "Error" at the top-left...

Comment: `a2enmod` is used to enable an **apache** module. To enable a **php** module, use `phpenmod`.

Comment: Yes but it is the apache php config that has issues. From the CLI and using simple php files it works fine. When in the shell if I do "phpenmod imap" (and "mysqli") it just returns with no error. If I then try and use "a2enmod imap" I get the same issue as before. In "/etc/php/7.4/mods-available" both the "imap.ini" and "mysqli.ini" exist, but the actual mods don't exist in "/etc/apache2/mods-available"...

Comment: You've misunderstood: "Apache module" doesn't mean "PHP module when PHP is running under Apache", it means "part of the Apache web server"; it's part of a completely different piece of software. You need to look into your actual error in PHP - it's not clear why you think these modules are even relevant.

Comment: @MarisaGiancarla Those are two different things. You use `a2enmod` to enable modules for the Apache webserver software, i.e. modules containing functions you can use to configure your webserver (such as `mod_rewrite`, `mod_ldap`, etc.). You use `phpenmod` to enable modules for the PHP programming language, i.e. modules containing functions you can use from PHP code. `php7.4-imap` and `php7.4-mysqli` are PHP modules. If `phpenmod` succeeded without errors, the modules should be enabled. You might have to restart Apache to load the new config files, but you shouldn't need to do anything else.